# Bind slave records are unreadable

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I noticed that a month or two ago that my bind records for the slave server became unreadable. The consequence of having an unreadable record is that it appears as though Webmin cannot read the record. I used to be able to go into Webmin on the slave machine to validate that the record was updated there, I can no longer do that.

It appears to still be a valid record because I can query the server itself and it returns the same data (NSLOOKUP, etc). So it appears as though Bind can read the file fine.

I would like this resolved, but I'm not sure where to look. Any thoughts?

Here is are the the master and slave records:

**===MASTER===**
BIND version 9.8.4
Debian Linux 7

```
$ttl 38400
servertest.com. IN  SOA testdns.com. foobar.testdns.com. (
        1377180224
        7200
        3600
        1209600
        38400 )
servertest.com. IN  NS  ns1.testdns.com.
servertest.com. IN  NS  ns2.testdns.com.
```

**===SLAVE===**
BIND version 9.9.2
Ubuntu Linux 13.04

```
^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^AR^V^Z_^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@[^@^A^@^F^@^@^@^@~
V^@^@^@^@^A^@^P
servertest^Ccom^@^@5^Gtestdns^Ccom^@^Ffoobar^Gtestdns^Ccom^@R^V^Z@^@^@
^\ ^@^@^N^P^@^Ru^@^@^@~V^@^@^@^@J^@^A^@^B^@^@^@^@~V^@^@^@^@^B^@^P
servertest^Ccom^@^@^Q^Cns1^Gtestdns^Ccom^@^@^Q^Cns2^Gtestdns^Ccom^@
```

All the details are there, but the slave is unreadable. (copy and pasted from PuTTy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are unreadable by default since BIND version 9.9.

Here is how you can make it readable:

```
# convert raw zone file "example.net.raw", containing data for zone example.net,
# to text-format zone file "example.net.text"

named-compilezone -f raw -F text -o example.net.text example.net example.net.raw

# convert text format zone file "example.net.text", containing data for zone
# example.net, to raw zone file "example.net.raw"

named-compilezone -f text -F raw -o example.net.raw example.net example.net.text
```

[Source](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00608/0/Converting-Zone-Files-Between-Text-and-Raw-Formats.html).

Comment: Excellent. That's what I needed to know.

Comment: You can get BIND to store the files in text rather raw format by adding `Masterfile-Format Text;` to the Zone options config.